# Bootstrap - How to set column height to more than one rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a bootstrap image grid I need to create for desktop, you can see the layout below.

[image: Proposed grid layout]

The problem I'm having is the center box goes over two rows so I can't figure out how to implement it. Might be a newbie question but any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How about you make the center box go in one row, and the outer boxes also go in that same one row, but you just put two boxes in one row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do..

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well">1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well">2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">3
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well">7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! didn't know you could nest rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

Grid has 12 column. Grid may overlap if the sum of total grid in your row is bigger than 12. you can put all content in a row then divide them on 3.Make first and third one 2 rows and make middle one your center row.

It will be easier to understand if you share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting your large box in one row, and the outer small boxes in the same row, where the two smaller boxes are just two boxes in the one row. (Both of height 50%).

Take a look at the snippet below for a working example:

```css
.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.box-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;  
  padding: 2px;
}

.big-box {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.col-3, .col-6 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="box-container"><div class="box"></div></div>
    <div class="box-container"><div class="box"></div></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="big-box"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="box-container"><div class="box"></div></div>
    <div class="box-container"><div class="box"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**Note:** I have use `col-3` and `col-6` for the fiddle to fit to the sample window, however, if you want responsiveness, you can use `col-md-3` and `col-md-6` (or `sm` instead of `md` if you wish for it to collapse at a smaller size).